# Missing DDL and table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I encounter the following errors after reinstalling MySQL Server. These seem to affect only one out of the several tables in the schema. The following errors are generated from MySQL Workbench.

- When running `CHECK TABLE myschema.mytable`, error is returned:

  > Table 'myschema.mytable' doesn't exist
- Trying to do `ALTER TABLE`, the following error box pops up:

  > Error getting DDL for object, Table 'myschema.mytable' doesn't exist

When I inspect the table, the Columns info (data type etc) and FKs info is there but the Indexes are gone. Inspection shows that data path directory is pointing to the correct .ibd file.

For the other tables, both the data and the metadata can be accessed. Some of these tables contain FKs which reference the affected table and they can still be read.

I can't be sure of what exactly is causing the errors. I reinstalled MySQL Server and copy-and-pasted the data directory (the .frm and .ibd files) after the installation. I read elsewhere that this might have caused the problem by corrupting the .ibd.

Is there any way to recover the table (or the whole schema altogether), or recover the DDL which the error suggests to be missing?

Win 7, MySQL Server 5.6.28

Comment: Use the mysql commandline tool.  See whether it can see and interact with the table.